# Insert Bulk of data to Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I am suffering from performance issues when inserting a milion rows into a PostgreSQL database.

I am sending a JSON object which has an array with a milion rows.

For each row i create a record in the database table. I also tried this with multiple insert at once, but the problem remains.

I am not sure how to handle this, I have read that the COPY command is fastests.

How can I improve the performance?

**My JSON Object with log as an array**:
array Log has a milion rows.

```
{"type":"monitoring","log":[
["2016-10-12T20:33:21","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.0","24.00","1.83","-0.00","1","1","-100.00"],
["2016-10-12T20:33:23","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.0","24.00","1.52","-0.61","1","1","-100.00"]]}
```

**My current code**(I am building a dynamic statement so that i can execute multiple rows at once):

```
IF(NOT b_first_line) THEN
          s_insert_query_values = right(s_insert_query_values, -1); --remove te leading comma

          EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO log_rlda
                  (record_node_id, log_line, log_value, timestamp, record_log_id)
          VALUES %s;', s_insert_query_values);

          s_insert_query_values = '';
          i_num_lines_buffered = 0;
        END IF;
      END IF;
```

**s_insert_query_values contains:**

Each value inside the array within "log", needs to be inserted in its own row(in colum: log_value). This is how the INSERT looks like(reference to s_insert_query_values):

```
INSERT INTO log_rlda
                  (record_node_id, log_line, log_value, timestamp, record_log_id)
          VALUES  
     (806, 1, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (807, 1, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (808, 1, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (809, 1, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (810, 1, 0.0, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (811, 1, 24.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (768, 1, 1.83, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (769, 1, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (728, 1, 1, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (771, 1, 1, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (729, 1, -100.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:21', 386),
     (806, 2, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (807, 2, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (808, 2, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (809, 2, 0.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (810, 2, 0.0, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (811, 2, 24.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (768, 2, 1.52, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (769, 2, -0.61, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (728, 2, 1, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (771, 2, 1, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386),
     (729, 2, -100.00, '2016-10-12 20:33:23', 386)
```

**Solution(i_node_id_list contains ID's i selected before this query):**

```
SELECT i_node_id_list[log_value_index] AS record_node_id,
                    e.log_line-1 AS log_line,
                    items.log_value::double precision as log_value,
                    to_timestamp((e.line->>0)::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as "timestamp",
                    i_log_id as record_log_id
              FROM (VALUES (log_data::json)) as data (doc),
                json_array_elements(doc->'log') with ordinality as e(line, log_line),
                json_array_elements_text(e.line)     with ordinality as items(log_value, log_value_index)
              WHERE  log_value_index > 1 --dont include timestamp value (shouldnt be written as log_value)
              AND  log_line  > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of unnesting.

```
select e.log_line, items.log_value, e.line -> 0 as timestamp
from (
  values ('{"type":"monitoring","log":[
  ["2016-10-12T20:33:21","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.0","24.00","1.83","-0.00","1","1","-100.00"],
  ["2016-10-12T20:33:23","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.0","24.00","1.52","-0.61","1","1","-100.00"]]}'::json)
) as data (doc), 
  json_array_elements(doc->'log') with ordinality as e(line, log_line), 
  json_array_elements(e.line)   with ordinality as items(log_value, log_value_index)
where log_value_index > 1;
```

The first call to json_array_elements() extracts all array elements from the `log` attribute. The `with ordinality` allows us to identify each row in that array. The second call then gets each element from the lines, again the `with ordinality` allows us to find out the position in the array.

The above query returns this:

```
log_line | log_value | timestamp            
---------+-----------+----------------------
       1 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "0.0"     | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "24.00"   | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "1.83"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "-0.00"   | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "1"       | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "1"       | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       1 | "-100.00" | "2016-10-12T20:33:21"
       2 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "0.00"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "0.0"     | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "24.00"   | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "1.52"    | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "-0.61"   | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "1"       | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "1"       | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
       2 | "-100.00" | "2016-10-12T20:33:23"
```

The result of the above statement can then be used to directly insert the data without looping over it. That should be a lot faster then doing a lot individual inserts.

I'm unsure however how you can integrate the correct `record_node_id` or `record_log_id` into the above result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer

The data is unnested in a different manner.

For each value in the "line array", except for the first value, a row is inserted in log_rlda.

Explanation of the columns in log_rlda:

record_node_id  Refers to a record node, which describes the meaning of the value.
log_line   The line number in the log data
log_value  each value 
timestamp  the first value in the "line array"
record_log_id refers to the set of data


I answerd your first question as to what "s_insert_query_values" contains.

Comment: to solve the issue of integrating the correct record_node_id, i have editted the following statement to select the right ID from an array of ID's i gathered before.

I use the log_value_index, to iterate through it. It works pretty good and i have gained a significant performance boost so far. I added the solution to the topic